# Replacing a specific word from java script files in C#

Tags: c#, replace

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> Substitutions =
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
        {"valueToFind1" , "valueToPut1"},
        {"valueToFindN" , "valueToPutN"},
    };

private static void UpdateScript(string path)
{
    string source = File.ReadAllText(path);

    foreach (var pair in Substitutions.OrderByDescending(p => p.Key.Length))
        source = source.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);

    File.WriteAllText(path, source);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSmf1.png)

Well before coming towards the problem let me explain what I have done so far, I had text file which contains sample of strings, by using each string i had created a folder and taking first two part of name ex "Mobilink_user" I matched this with the folder present in folder "TDScript" and then moved the copied the scripts in it to the matched folder. Now you can see there are multiple folders and each folder have 23 java script file now  I want replace word "{Table}" in script to their respective folder name. Kindly go through the code and guide me how it will work.

Comment: You are reading a text file and you want to replace word which matches ValueToFind1 with valueToPut1, right?

Comment: @KemalGüler No, we have folder "TDScript", in which there are let's say 11 sub folders and in theses folders we have 23 java script files each. Now I want  to replace the word "Table" in every java script file to their respective folder's name.

Comment: And what does the code posted have to do with that?

Comment: @Magnus I can't under stand that code so that's why I posted this code 
above I tell the problem which I am facing in the code please try to help my problem